# NodeJS, AngularJS - Publishing events in server and listening

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am developing a web app using the MEAN stack. On my Node server I have a POST route - **/api/gps** to which a remote device keeps posting GPS data regularly with an interval of 10 seconds or so. I service this POST request by taking the post body and saving the details such as timestamp, tripid, latitude, longitude etc to my MonngoDB collection. 
Now here is where I am stuck -
I have a route - **/displaymap** which is rendered by **displaymap.jade** and associated with a controller - **MapDisplayCtrl**. Here I have to display the map of the most recently posted GPS data from the device. So how do I update the map as soon as I get new POST data to /api/gps?

app.js file

```
var GPSData = mongoose.model('GPSData', gpsSchema);
app.post('/api/particle', function(req, res) {
    GPSData.create({
                tripid : req.body.tripId,
                latitude: req.body.latitude,
                longitude: req.body.longitude,
                timestamp: Date.now()
            }, function(err, doc) {
                if(err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.send(doc);
                    //here is where I want to publish an event say, 'SendMapData'
                    //that sends co-ordinates to the controller
                }
            });
    });
```

MapDisplayCtrl.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp');

myApp.controller('MapDisplayCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
     //listen to the 'SendMapData' event and get the co-ordinates
     //draw a google map using the co-ordinates
});
```

I guess all I need is an event emitter at NodeJS side and a listener at AngularJS side, but I don't know how to implement it. I hope I've give enough information for you to answer. If you need anymore info i'll provide it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `socket.io` to communicate in real time between server & client.

Server:

```
//here is where I want to publish an event say, 'SendMapData'
//that sends co-ordinates to the controller
socket.emit('SendMapData', data);
```

Controller:

```
 //listen to the 'SendMapData' event and get the co-ordinates
 //draw a google map using the co-ordinates
 socket.on('SendMapData', function(serverData) {
     //do what you want with data received from server.
 });
```

For docs check [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) (not the best documentation, but it helps)

**EDIT**
In order to use `socket.io` inside an angular app, to be "the angular way" I have build a service for this (not all by myself, inspired by SO):

```
MYAPP.factory('socket', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    var socketMethods = {},
        socketio;

    //fn: connect
    //desc: connect to server
    socketMethods.connect = function(server){
        if( ! angular.isUndefined(socketio)) return;

        var ioUrl = 'ws://'+ server.fullAddr;
        var ioManager = {transports: ['websocket', 'polling'], reconnectionAttempts: Infinity};
        socketio = io(ioUrl, ioManager);
    }

    //fn: on
    //desc: receive data from server
    socketMethods.on = function(eventName, callback){
        //check if event is already registered; 'connect' registered by default, ignore it.
        if(socketio.hasListeners(eventName) && eventName != 'connect') return;
        socketio.on(eventName, function(serverData, respondToServer){
            $timeout(function(){
                callback.call(socketio, serverData, respondToServer);
            });
        });
    }

    //fn: emit
    //desc: send data to server
    socketMethods.emit = function(eventName, data, callback){
        socketio.emit(eventName, data, function(serverResponse){
            $timeout(function(){
                if(callback) callback.call(socketio, serverResponse);
            });
        });
    }

    return socketMethods;
}]);
```

...and you can inject 'socket' in your controller, open a socket connection and listen/emit events.